# I2C 3.3 to 5.0 V conversion

Tags: arduino, voltage, i2c, digital-communications

I'm trying to interface a 3.3V I<sup>2</sup>C device to a 5V Arduino.

I don't have any problem with SCL line.
I can use a simple voltage divider but I have an issue with the SDA line as this is bi-directional.

I'm not at all sure how to handle this. I have though of adding a pair of diodes, with a voltage divider on the slave input side and nothing extra on the master input.

Are there any other solutions?

Comment: Future readers should be aware that even though OP might only use SCL in one direction, I2C generally allows SCL to be bidirectional.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Good document about the subject is [Bi-directional level shifter for I2C-bus and other systems](http://www.standardics.nxp.com/support/documents/i2c/pdf/an97055.pdf) which uses a single mosfet as a bi-directional level shifter.

Comment: I like the Philips circuit.  Clever.  It might in some ways be better if the I2C outputs didn't have to sink all the current from all the pull-ups, but designing an active I2C repeater is hard; I don't think it can be done with normal logic, since the repeater must be able to detect a rising edge and react to it before any I2C devices can.

Comment: The link is dead!

Comment: @Zimano Internet Archive to the rescue: http://web.archive.org/web/20121222214842/http://ics.nxp.com/support/documents/interface/pdf/an97055.pdf

Comment: @Adrian Awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

To expand upon sivu's answer, this is a common use for so-called "bus switches" which are basically logic-controlled MOSFETs. Using discrete MOSFETs has some drawbacks (parasitic capacitance / capacitive coupling being one) and it can be tricky to choose a good MOSFET. The bus switches are optimized for use in high-speed logic circuits.

Several manufacturers make them, including Fairchild, TI, IDT, and Pericom. Take a look at the [NC7SZ384](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/pf/NC/NC7SZ384.html).

See the following appnotes, among others:

- [Fairchild AN-996](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/an/AN/AN-996.pdf)
- [TI SCDA003B](http://focus.ti.com/lit/an/scda003b/scda003b.pdf)
- [IDT AN-157](http://www.idt.com/products/getdoc.cfm?docid=7464)
- [Pericom AB-008](http://www.pericom.com/pdf/applications/AB008.pdf)

Answer (score 8):

Many Arduino's have onboard support to run at 3.3 V. Actually, all can run at 3.3 V and the FTDI chip schematic explains how in an example. Paul, who made the [Teensy USB Arduino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Arduino_compatibles#Arduino-compatible_boards_with_software-compatibility_only), had suggested that I could splice the USB cable open and supply a 3.3 V voltage in place of the V<sub>CC</sub> line of the cable. You could try this. But there are also other options.

1. Check the logic levels for the Arduino. I believe they support 3.3 V as logic HIGH even on a 5 V sourced Atmel. [A SparkFun article](http://www.rocketnumbernine.com/2009/04/10/5v-33v-bidirectional-level-converter/) states: "*Connecting a 3.3 V digital output pin to a 5 V input pin is often straightforward. Most devices are fairly tolerant to the minimum voltage that they will accept as a digital high value. Most Atmel microcontrollers, for example, accept anything above 0.6*V<sub>CC</sub> as high, so the 3.3 V device must output a level above 3 V (0.6*5 V).*"
2. Purchase one of the Arduino clones that has jumpered 3.3 V and 5 V selectors. I use the [RBBB cloan](http://moderndevice.com/RBBB_revB) which I have set the supply cables FTDI chip to 3.3 V. But there are many others that have actual 3.3 V configuration options, including one of the recent official Arduinos if I remember correctly. You could also use the Teensy USB with his Arduino plugin and follow the directions on his site to install a [3.3 V regulator](http://www.pjrc.com/teensy/3volt.html).
3. Splice the USB cable and provide a laboratory power supply quality 3.3 V source in place of the V<sub>CC</sub> line of the USB cable. It should be low current, as Paul has suggested. Hence, either a good quality voltage source. You could also just put a couple of batteries in series to get the desired voltage.
4. If you are interested, I can try to examine the schematic of your Arduino and perhaps it is possible to make a change to the FTDI configuration that would allow for 3.3 V.

Lastly, we have a discussion that might interest you about this over [here on Chiphacker about uni-directional and bi-directional solutions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/622/bi-directional-step-up-and-step-down-3-3v-5-etc) for voltage step down. [This article on SparkFun](http://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/65) mentioned by todbot is useful, as is the discussion on bidrectional [MOSFET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOSFET) article linked from SparkFun. To summarize the SparkFun article:

- Inline resistor. Uni-directional. Step-down only -- reduces current, ICs I/O clamping diodes can limit max input.
- Series resistors. Uni-directional. Step-down only, but granular.
- Diode. Uni-directional. Step-down. Safer. High from 5 V blocks diode; the 3.3 V side then ties to high. But, if you reverse the diode configuration, couldn't you also step-up?
- MOSFET. Bi-directional. Step-down or step-up.
- In comments: Optical isolation example: 4N25. High current.
- In comments: Zener diode example: 1N4728A
- In comments: 74HC244/125 uni-directional

Answer (score 6):

There are ICs available specifically for level-shifting I2C:

- LTC4300A-2 (http://www.linear.com/pc/productDetail.jsp?navId=H0,C1,C1007,C1070,P2296)
- PCA9306 (http://focus.ti.com/docs/prod/folders/print/pca9306.html)

I don't know what kind of constraints you have on your design, but I would think using a dedicated IC would be easier then coming up with your own solution.