# How do I get an Arduino (5 V) and MPR121 (3.3 V) to talk?

Tags: arduino, sensor, i2c, level-shifting, capsense

I have the [Sparkfun MPR121 I2C Capacitive touch sensor breakout board](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/9695)

I have read that it uses 3.3 V, I know that I can't just connect up the 3.3 V power supply output from the Arduino as the communications lines would require 3.3 V as well. How do I connect up the other lines?

I have found a [tutorial at Sparkfun's website](http://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/65). The 3rd diagram using the diode - would that be the best way to interface the sensor to the Arduino?

Any ideas or information would be great, my knowledge is pretty low.

Comment: Connecting a (different) 3.3V I2C sensor to Arduino http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/708/i2c-3-3-to-5-0-v-conversion

Answer (score 14):

You can do it using exactly two transistors, which is pretty slick.

[image]

This comes straight from a [Philips application note](http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/an97055.pdf).

Comment: That Phillips appnote is practically a classic.

Comment: @reemrevnivek yes, and very clever indeed

Comment: I count 2 more pull-ups than normal.  Not quite exact :P

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the current draw of the device in question the 3.3V output of the arduino should suffice. As for the communication lines, you'll need some type of level shifter. Looks like SparkFun has a solution for that too:

http://www.sparkfun.com/products/8745

Comment: I have one of those at home, just not sure on how to hook it up as I2C has more than one line. and is bi-directional

Comment: According to some of the user comments on that page, the 'TX' lines are supposed to be bi-directional. So I assume you'd connect SDA to TX1 and SCL to TX2, for example.

Comment: If you look at the Data sheet It is almost the same as the Schematic that vicatcu posted in his answer. And as experience goes they are bi-directional.