# TTL voltage shift from 5 to 3.3 Volts "UART"

Tags: voltage-regulator, uart, level-shifting, ttl

I want to make serial communication with a device which works on 0-5 Volt TTL level. But my serial chip uses 3.3 Volt logic. (this is an UART communication)

I know that I need a step down at least for the TX pin of device (which will be RX on my serial chip). I wanted to go with normal resistor voltage divider but I'm assuming it will cause problems in high speed transmissions. Can you recommend a good, easy to use chip for this task?

Also, do I need to have a voltage step up from 3.3V to 5V for the device's RX (my serial chip's TX)? I heard that anything above 2.4 volts should be considered high. What do you think?

And I have question about whether the converter should be inverting or not? How can I determine this?

Comment: While you dont say whether this is for I2C communication, I would suggest you to take a look at [this](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/708/i2c-3-3-to-5-0-v-conversion) question and it answers. Especially the linked [document](http://ics.nxp.com/support/documents/interface/pdf/an97055.pdf) may be helpful.

Comment: @PetPaulsen - I2C doesn't use TX and RX, sounds more like UART. OP also doesn't talk about a clock.

Comment: Yeah this is about UART...sorry for not being clear about it!

Comment: What serial chip are you using?  If it's something like the [FT230X](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/ICs/FT230X.html), those chips are specifically listed as being 5V tolerant and compatible even when using 3.3V I/O levels, so you wouldn't need any conversion at all.  You might check if your chips are similar.

Comment: It's some TI microcontroller which in datasheet says 3.3V

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The 2.4 V is the minimum for a high level TTL *output*. A TTL input needs at least 2.0 V, to give you a 400 mV noise margin. But that's for *TTL* devices, or TTL compatible, like HCT-CMOS. An HCMOS device will typically need 0.7 Vdd as minimum for a high level. For a 5 V supply that's 3.5 V, so you probably won't make it. You can use an HCT [single gate IC](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT1G32.pdf) as level shifter.

The resistor divider probably won't cause much problems, except for very high speeds. Since this is less than 100 kbps UART, chip resistors shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks. Yes its UART communication. I will try the prototype with resistor voltage divider, but can you name a decent chip for this job?

Comment: @sean - What's the bit rate?

Comment: The baud rate is either 57k or 19k

Comment: @sean - *ab-so-lute-ly* no problem with resistors! Just do it :-).

Comment: What is wrong with the voltage dividers when it comes to high speed? I need to communicate my MSP430 MCU working at 3.3V with a 5V TTL UART still camera http://store.linksprite.com/jpeg-color-camera-2m-pixel-serial-uart-interface-ttl-level/
It works at 115200 bps. Do you think the voltage dividers on RX and TX lines won't do the job?

Comment: The problem with voltage dividers is they have a relatively high output impedance. Combined with stray capacitance this rounds off the edges of the pulses. Also if the line idles high (as most logic-level serial does) then they constantly waste power.

Comment: If you want a small chip to take a line from 5V to 3.3V you might consider the 74LVC1G32.