# Connection of EZ430-RF2500 development tool with PIC18f877

Tags: pic, msp430, interface

I want to conect the ez430-rf2500 development tool with PIC16f877 throught uart, do I have to use a max232 chip in order to be able to communicate between those two MCUs or it can be done without it.

Comment: It might be worth adding what voltage both systems are running at.

Comment: I guess, @Kostas meant [PIC **16** F877](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en026561), because PIC **18** F877 model doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect the PIC's UART to the MSP430's UART directly, if the power supply voltages are the same.  So, it is possible get away without an RS-232 driver such as MAX232.  Of course, you would need to connect the grounds together.

As a side note, MAX232 generates the true [RS-232 voltage levels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232#Voltage_levels).  These are higher than the voltage levels, which the UART outputs.  The benefit of higher voltage levels is that the true RS-232 is more immune to interference.

#### What if the power supply voltages aren't the same?

PIC16F877 can use supply voltages between +2V and +5.5V.  MSP430F2274 on the ez430 can use supply voltages between +1.8V to +3.6V.  Suppose that the MSP430 runs off +3.3v, and the PIC runs off +5V.  MSP430F2274 doesn't have inputs that are 5V-tolerant.

The supply voltage ranges overlap.  May be, lowering the supply of the PIC16F877 to +3.3V is an option.  You may need to lower the oscillator frequency.  Check that other components, which share the power supply rail with the PIC can operate off +3.3V.

If your design doesn't allow you to lower the PIC's supply voltage from +5V to +3.3V, there are level shifters (or level translator) ICs.  See [this post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/39463/7036) for details.

Comment: Nick thank you for your detailed answer and yes I meant 16f877 sorry for that ;) If I use a voltage divider at the PICs TX and RX pins to get the +3.3V whould it fix that problem?

Comment: @Kostas  Voltage divider would work.  Your baud rate is probably not too high.